# JavaFX, TextFields, EventHandler

Tags: java, javafx

I'm just learning JavaFX and watching tutorials.
Its a lot of information to process, so I'm starting off with a simple
BMI Calculator app. 
Im not including the BMI class, but it has a constructor of:
BMI(double height, double weight, String gender)

**Problems:**

1. My EventHandler is not working. I tried to do the same as a tutorial, but I can't get it work. I tried with a simple Print if eventSource = button
2. So I will have 3 TextFields where the user enters the 3 specified values, height, weight gender.
   When the user does this, I want to use my BMI class and create a new BMI using these 3 values. I found a methode: "textfield.getAccesibleText();
   Maybe that could work but I cant find out since my eventhandler isn't working.

All in all, the user should press the "Calculate" button after entering the 3 values, I will then create a Bmi using my Bmi class, and display the value of that Bmi in a new box. (I will have to add the box where Bmi) is displayed later.

**Get Eventhandler working, being able to take values from textfields (like scanner) , create a new Bmi, create a new box where I will display the value of that Bmi. (I got a methode in my BMI class which calculates the BMI**

```
public class Main extends Application  {
Button b1;
Button b2;
Text g;
Text w; 
Text h; 

TextField g1; 
TextField w1;
TextField h1; 
@Override


public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

 g = new Text("Gender:");
 w = new Text("Weight:");
 h = new Text("Height");
 g1 = new TextField();
 w1 = new TextField();
 h1 = new TextField();



b1 = new Button("Calculate BMI!");
b2 = new Button("Reset BMI");

GridPane grid = new GridPane();

grid.setMinSize(400, 200);

grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
  grid.setVgap(5); 
  grid.setHgap(5);

  grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); 

  grid.add(g, 0, 0);
  grid.add(g1, 1, 0);
  grid.add(w, 0, 1);
  grid.add(w1, 1, 1);
  grid.add(h, 0, 2);
  grid.add(h1, 1, 2);
  grid.add(b1, 0, 3);
  grid.add(b2, 1, 3);

  b1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: purple; -fx-text-fill: white;"); 
  b2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: purple; -fx-text-fill: white;");
  grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: GREEN;"); 

  Scene scene = new Scene(grid);

  stage.setScene(scene);

  stage.show();


}


public void handle(ActionEvent event){
    if(event.getSource() == b1){
    //do something
}
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);



}}
```

Comment: my JavaFX is a little rusty, but don't you have to flag the components with @FXML for the fx:id to be associated with the component?

Comment: @M.Goodman The OP doesn't use `FXMLLoader`  so `@FXML` is not needed.

Comment: please stick to one problem per question. And always provide a [mcve] that demonstrates that single problem. _M_inimal means, that you remove everything that's not related: in the case of a event handler that's not working, just show one textfield in a most simple layout (no need for a grid with whatever constraints), your handler and how you wire both.

Answer (score 1):

It seem like you have the method to handle the action event but the handler itself is never attached to neither the buttons nor the text fields. In order to do so you need to provide an [EventHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html) interface implementation, for example:

```
button.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, (ActionEvent event) -> {
    // your code here
});
```

See [Working with Event Handlers](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/handlers.htm) for more details.

However as @kleopatra mentioned a better practice is to provide the event handler using the appropriate `setOnXxx()` method, for example:

```
button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    // your code here
});
```

---

> Do you also know how to "gather" the user input in the textfiles, like a scanner, then create a new Bmi with them and finally display that number in a new box or something similar.

Here is the part where you need to figure out the business model in order to generate the class or classes that will hold the data from the controls. A good candidate is a `BmiData` POJO as follows:

```
public class BmiData {

    private String gender;
    private Double height;
    private Double weight;

    // Constructor, getters and setters

    public Double calculateBmi() {
        // perform the calculation here
    }
}
```

Then the event handler attached to the "Calculate BMI" button is a good candidate to collect the data from the text fields into a `BmiData` object and finally display the result to the user. I'd suggest you to look into MVC (Model-View-Controller) design pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out. I suppose I could make a class for my GUI? Then tie it togheter with my other classes in a main program?

Comment: Yes, of course. It'll be much better actually. Something that I forgot to include in the answer is that in most cases event handlers are not reusable accross mutliple controls in the sense that each control is responsible for a specific and different task. Keeping this in mind, you can use lamba expressions in order to implement your handlers: `b1.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, (event) -> { /*  code here */ });`

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tommorow. Do you also know how to "gather" the user input in the textfiles, like a scanner, then create a new Bmi with them and finally display that number in a new box or something similar. TextFields gender, height, weight, Bmi b = new Bmi(t1,t2,t3) , b.calculate <= display b.calculate (methode I wrote in my bmi class which gives an int)

Comment: while you spotted the basic error (handler not registered in any way), your code is suboptimal in several aspects: a) don't let a top-level class implement an eventHandler, b) for simple things answers should stick to common patterns: here that would be to button.setOnAction (vs. button.addEventHandler) - your comment is by far better anwer <g>

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for the feedback! I guess I was too lazy to write the correct answer and just went for the short not-so-good one :)